# apt-get update error 14.04

Tags: command-line

Im new to linux and im having this problem whilst trying to fix a grub boot problem. [this is the problem](http://tinypic.com/r/13z954g/8) if someone could please help me with this. thank you.

ps, freshly installed via DVD, fresh out the box dell inspiron 11 3000 series. 4gb ram.

Comment: Add sudo in front of the command.

Comment: @Seth This is obviously a n00b mistake. Look again at the screenshot. This isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @biggles While the answers to that question *do* solve the problem, you are right, we do have a more optimal candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Linux community and Ask Ubuntu! This is one of the newbie mistakes that I know I've made in the past, and it's a rather easy one to fix. Just make sure to use `sudo`  before the command to avoid this error. For example:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then it will prompt you for your password. Don't be worried when you type in your password and nothing shows up. Just press enter, and if you entered it correctly, the command will run just fine.

**Explanation:** Certain functions, like package management, require you to be root. `sudo` is one of the ways to get root access. All it requires is for you to have administrator rights - I'm assuming you do since you installed Ubuntu yourself. If you're not sure, just run `groups` in the terminal, and if it lists the `sudo` group, you have administrator rights and can use `sudo`.

However, with great power comes great responsibility. Don't use sudo unless you are **absolutely sure** that you need root access. Package management is one of the few times you'll need this. Another example is if you're editing system configuration files under `/etc` (although I'm certain you're not on that level yet).

This should give you plenty of information so you know what this weird `sudo` thing is for. If you need anything else, just ask. I will be glad to help.